# Bootstrap Drop down menu not closing on Tablets

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having issues with Bootstrap Drop down menu Click Event on Andriod tablets and IPADS, When i click on it, It opens BUT doesn't close. Except i click outside of the menu (a blank area of the webpage)

Although, this issue does not happen on desktop, Only when viewing on tablets.

This is the code

```
<div class="container" >
    <!-- Grid demo navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navigation" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-grid" class="navbar-toggle">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">COMPANY NAME</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar-collapse-grid" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


          <!-- Classic list -->
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle  blackbg">MY MENU
        <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="link">MY FIRST LINK</li>
            <li><a href="link">MY SECOND LINK</li>
            <li><a href="link">MY THIRD LINK</li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I think this is an issue with click event on tablets, but i don't know how to solve this.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using tap events with Twitter Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215096/using-tap-events-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: ok, thanks..Let me check it out

Comment: I have read the post, but i don't want a integrate a full touch plugin,and i dont want to use jquery mobile, Because the menu actually working when you first click on it. Its the second click that is having issues

Comment: Am looking for a bootstrap js hack actually, if possible

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9543#issuecomment-22806212 -- this person, Petercopter, has a fix for it, I hope.